# How to write script for changing '+' , '-' symbol in nested accordion?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using nested panel group , but the issue is this that nested accordion's panel-heading or plus symbol is not working well. So somebody please help me to correct my script , so that i can collapse and change the nested panel-group's icon also.

```js
function toggleIcon(e) {
    $(e.target)
        .prev('.panel-heading')
        .find(".more-less")
        .toggleClass('glyphicon-plus glyphicon-minus');

        $(e.target)
        .prev('.panel-heading')
        .toggleClass('highlight');       
}

$('.panel-group').on('hidden.bs.collapse', toggleIcon);
$('.panel-group').on('shown.bs.collapse', toggleIcon);
//$('panel-heading').addClass("highlight");
```

```css
.panel-group .panel {
        border-radius: 0;
        box-shadow: none;
        border-color: #EEEEEE;
    }

    .panel-default > .panel-heading {
        padding: 0;
        border-radius: 0;
        color: #212121;
        background-color: #FAFAFA;
        border-color: #EEEEEE;
    }

    .panel-title {
        font-size: 14px;
    }

    .panel-title > a {
        display: block;
        padding: 15px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .more-less {
        float: right;
        color: #212121;
    }

    .panel-default > .panel-heading + .panel-collapse > .panel-body {
        border-top-color: #EEEEEE;
    }

/* ----- v CAN BE DELETED v ----- */
body {
    background-color: #26a69a;
}

.demo {
    padding-top: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 60px;
}

.highlight{background: #ff0 !important; transition: 2s ease all;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>


<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container demo">
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                        <i class="more-less glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
                        Collapsible Group Item #1
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                <div class="panel-body">
                      Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                        <i class="more-less glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
                        Collapsible Group Item #2
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>

            <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
                <div class="panel-body">

                    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                        <i class="more-less glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
                        Collapsible Group Item #3
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>

            <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
                <div class="panel-body">
                   
<!-- nested panel-group start -->

 <div class="panel-group" id="accordion2" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne1">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne1" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne1">
                        <i class="more-less glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
                        Collapsible Group Item #1
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne1" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne1">
                <div class="panel-body">
                      Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo2">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseTwo2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo2">
                        <i class="more-less glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
                        Collapsible Group Item #2
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>

            <div id="collapseTwo2" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo2">
                <div class="panel-body">

                    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree3">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseThree3" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree3">
                        <i class="more-less glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
                        Collapsible Group Item #3
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>

            <div id="collapseThree3" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree3">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- panel-group -->  

<!-- nested panel-group ends -->

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- panel-group -->  
</div><!-- container -->
```

In above code's result the '+' and '-' symbol of nested accordion is not changing. that's my problem.

I need that How can i catch the nested panel group by accordion id so that another script may apply in that one only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what happen is that you have 2 div with the class `panel-group` one inside the other so when you click in the second `panel-group` you fire the event two times witch cause the problem. I added a setTimeout that wait for 20ms.

```js
function toggleIcon(e) {
    $(e.target)
        .prev('.panel-heading')
        .find(".more-less")
        .toggleClass('glyphicon-plus glyphicon-minus');

        $(e.target)
        .prev('.panel-heading')
        .toggleClass('highlight');
}

$('.panel-group').on('hidden.bs.collapse', toggleIcon);
$('.panel-group').on('shown.bs.collapse', toggleIcon);
//$('panel-heading').addClass("highlight");

$('.insider').on('hidden.bs.collapse', toggleIcon);
$('.insider').on('shown.bs.collapse', toggleIcon);
```

```css
.panel-group .panel {
        border-radius: 0;
        box-shadow: none;
        border-color: #EEEEEE;
    }

    .panel-default > .panel-heading {
        padding: 0;
        border-radius: 0;
        color: #212121;
        background-color: #FAFAFA;
        border-color: #EEEEEE;
    }

    .panel-title {
        font-size: 14px;
    }

    .panel-title > a {
        display: block;
        padding: 15px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .more-less {
        float: right;
        color: #212121;
    }

    .panel-default > .panel-heading + .panel-collapse > .panel-body {
        border-top-color: #EEEEEE;
    }

/* ----- v CAN BE DELETED v ----- */
body {
    background-color: #26a69a;
}

.demo {
    padding-top: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 60px;
}

.highlight{background: #ff0 !important; transition: 2s ease all;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>


<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container demo">
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                        <i class="more-less glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
                        Collapsible Group Item #1
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                <div class="panel-body">
                      Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                        <i class="more-less glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
                        Collapsible Group Item #2
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>

            <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
                <div class="panel-body">

                    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                        <i class="more-less glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
                        Collapsible Group Item #3
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>

            <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
                <div class="panel-body">
                   
<!-- nested panel-group start -->

 <div class="panel-group insider" id="accordion2" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne1">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne1" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne1">
                        <i class="more-less glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
                        Collapsible Group Item #1
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne1" class="panel-collapse collapse " role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne1">
                <div class="panel-body">
                      Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo2">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseTwo2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo2">
                        <i class="more-less glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
                        Collapsible Group Item #2
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>

            <div id="collapseTwo2" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo2">
                <div class="panel-body">

                    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree3">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseThree3" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree3">
                        <i class="more-less glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
                        Collapsible Group Item #3
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>

            <div id="collapseThree3" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree3">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- panel-group -->  

<!-- nested panel-group ends -->

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- panel-group -->  
</div><!-- container -->
```

Comment: First, Thankyou @evgeni fotia , but this still not working properly, if I open All three nested panel then symbol of one panel doesn't change properly. Secondaly  i want to ask that can we change by $(this) object  so that no issue will be with event.

Comment: @VikasSharma check the edit. This isn't my finale answer I just want to make sure if this is the result that you are looking for

Comment: Thank you for your response @evgeni. It works out for me.

Comment: one more query @evgeni  how should I do in this script   `  $(".collapse").on('show.bs.collapse', function(){
            $(this).parent().find(".glyphicon").removeClass("glyphicon-plus").addClass("glyphicon-minus");
        }).on('hide.bs.collapse', function(){
            $(this).parent().find(".glyphicon").removeClass("glyphicon-minus").addClass("glyphicon-plus");
        });`

Comment: @VikasSharma this is what you want `$(".collapse").on('show.bs.collapse', function(e){
if(this != e.target){ return 0;}
$(this).parent().find(".glyphicon:first").removeClass("glyphicon-plus").addClass("glyphicon-minus"); }).on('hide.bs.collapse', function(e){
if(this != e.target){ return 0;}
$(this).parent().find(".glyphicon:first").removeClass("glyphicon-minus").addClass("glyphicon-plus"); });`

Comment: Thankyou @evgeni fotia

Comment: @evegeni fotia   There is still error, when you click second time  on  parent panel of nested accordion then all nested panels displaying - symbol

Comment: @VikasSharma I don't understand. Also about witch code are you speaking about the one in the answer or the one in the comments

Comment: @VikasSharma If you are speaking about the one in the comment. make sure that you copied the code right because it's working just fine for me

Comment: @VikasSharma why have you changed the question to not answered?

Comment: when i'm removing the :first child from the script then its not working fine .. i'm taking about commented script with a small correction===> 
 `$(".collapse").on('show.bs.collapse', function(e){ if(this != e.target){ return 0;} $(this).parent().find(".glyphicon").removeClass("glyphicon-plus").addClass("glyphicon-minus");
        }).on('hide.bs.collapse', function(e){ if(this != e.target){ return 0;} $(this).parent().find(".glyphicon").removeClass("glyphicon-minus").addClass("glyphicon-plus");
        });`

Comment: @VikasSharma without `first` `find` will return all `glyphicon` inside the targeted `collapse`